# How to check who run updates or installed packages on Debian?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt

I'm in the rather strange situation where I don't trust all users with sudo rights and there's nothing I can do about it. I would like to check periodically if anyone but me installed any packages or even worse, run updates, without consulting me on my Debian/Ubuntu servers. On other servers running CentOS I use `yum history`. Is there a way to find out who's been naughty? I would sleep much better...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Check the log messages and search the package which got updated.

Comment: use this in your future  "HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "

or

echo 'export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "' >> ~/.bash_profile ; source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: [`etckeeper`](http://etckeeper.branchable.com/) is also a good idea to track changes. Commits are also triggered with `apt`.

Comment: OK, so HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T " changes the format of info I get from `history` by adding timestamp to it, which is useful, but it doesn't tell me which sudo user did it. Also, the info comes from command line history which I think is only updates if the user logs out. Not sure if it gets updated when the session crashes, timeout etc. Plus the one user I'm concerned about often leaves his session on forever in screen on such

Comment: @jofel Thanks, this sounds like a great tool, I'll definitely look into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that the other users aren't trying to hide anything from you, they're just a bit clueless or annoying. If they want to hide, they can, and there's nothing you can do about it.

There are logs of apt usage in `/var/log/apt` and logs of dpkg usage in `/var/log/dpkg.log`. They tell you what packages operations were made when; they don't tell you by whom but you can get a hint by comparing with the output of `last`.

You can get useful tracking of package manipulation and configuration changes by putting `/etc` under version control. [etckeeper](https://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/) (available as a package on Debian and Ubuntu) does that very well. Install it and edit `/etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf` to configure it to your liking:

- Set `VCS` to your favorite version control system.
- Make sure that `AVOID_DAILY_AUTOCOMMITS` is commented out. If someone makes a change in `/etc`, it will be recorded in an automatic commit. There won't be a meaningful log message but at least the change and its approximate date will be tracked.
- Make sure that `AVOID_COMMIT_BEFORE_INSTALL` is commented out. Again, there will be an automatic commit before any use of APT tools (`apt`, `apt-get`, `aptitude`, etc.). There's always an automatic commit after package management operations that lists what changes were made.

Make sure that the proper environment variables or configuration files are set up to record the identity of the committer. Depending on how people gain root (through `su`, `sudo`, etc.), this may mean modifying root's `.profile` or `.bashrc` (if people use `sudo -s`), or maybe even adding a commit hook to grab `$SUDO_USER` to arrange that the committer on record isn't just `root`.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles, in the absence of `yum history` like tool this is a great overview of my options.